# SlimDX9 - Device.Reset with RenderToSurface

Tags: c#, reset, slimdx

I have a kind of specific question.

I've been trying to reset a SlimDX9 device after window resize to change the resolution. Everything is in Pool.Managed, no Fonts, no Stateblocks, and everything works BUT a texture+surface+RenderToSurface combo. I need the texture as a renderTarget for shaders, for postprocessing later, so I need it to resize to clientsize as well as the backbuffer does.

I do create the combo like this:

```
rtTexture = new Texture(this.Device, this.owner.ClientSize.Width, this.owner.ClientSize.Height, 1, Usage.RenderTarget, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);
rtSurface = rtTexture.GetSurfaceLevel(0);
rtHelper = new RenderToSurface(this.Device, this.owner.ClientSize.Width, this.owner.ClientSize.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Format.D24S8);
```

When the window is resized, I do

```
rtTexture.Dispose();
rtSurface.Dispose();
```

and I've tried both

```
rtHelper.OnLostDevice();
```

and

```
rtHelper.Dispose();
```

And of course, after Device.Reset(getParameters()) I recreate the resources/call rtHelper.OnResetDevice(), both did not work. I tried every combination possible with Dispose()s and OnDeviceLost().

After unsuccessfull reset and the the usual InvalidCall, I got this message

```
All user created D3DPOOL_DEFAULT surfaces must be freed before ResetEx can succeed. ResetEx Fails.
```

So I PIXed the application, and found out that neither the texture nor the surface are disposed (there is "never" in the destroyed column) DESPITE the fact, that .Dispose() is explicitly called on both those objects and IsDisposed was true BEFORE the Device.Reset().

Deleting the combo makes the reset go just fine. The problem is somewhere in the RenderToSurface reset and/or the texture+surface.

I use the RenderToSurface like this:

```
rtHelper.BeginScene(rtSurface, new Viewport(0, 0, this.owner.ClientSize.Width, this.owner.ClientSize.Height));
{
    Device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, FogColor, 1, 0);
    terrainEffect.BeginPass(0);
    RenderTiles();
    terrainEffect.EndPass();
}
rtHelper.EndScene(Filter.None);
```

Is it even possible? Is it a bug in SlimDX? What can I do? 
Can I maybe access the unmanaged resources somehow, and destroy them manually?

Please help, I have no idea what to do next. I'd greatly appreciate any response on this. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I've tried to go around the RenderToSurface and use Device.get/setRenderTarget() and the problem persists, the surface and the texture are not destroyed by the Dispose() before the Device.Reset().

Answer (score 1):

I've got it figured out!
For anyone experiencing same issue:

If you are using a texture created in one shader pass, assigning it to the shader and using it in second pass, be sure to set the texture after you used it (before `Device.Present()`) to `null`. Like so:

```
terrainEffect.SetTexture(hRTTexture, null);
```

where `hRTTexture` is a handler for the texture. Seems that shaders lock the texture, and SlimDX cannot dispose such texture (and associated surface) if the shader has this lock on it.

Hope this helps someone.